# How to get test tokens for Kusama

Tags: kusama, test-network

I read this https://guide.kusama.network/docs/kusama-claims/#third-party-claims-processes but I don't have DOT token when you had your Genesis block. So, how can I get test tokens now?

I'm joining your hackathon and wanna build dapps on your Kusama.

Answer (score 4):

Kusama is not a test network, but you might be interested in the Rococo network, documented here: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-pdk#rococo-testnet